# How to add Security provider in a Spring application using Javaconfig?

Tags: java, spring, security, bouncycastle, spring-java-config

I'm trying to add BouncyCastle to my Spring application but I am not sure how to add the provider to the `java.security.Security` provider list using JavaConfig.

Using XML configuration, I can use the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` similar the following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
  <property name="staticMethod" value="java.security.Security.addProvider"/>
  <property name="arguments">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

However, I'm not sure of the right way to do this using JavaConfig.  Should I still be using the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`?  I presumed since it is pure java, there would be a more direct approach.  At the moment, I've added the directive to a `@PostConstruct` method in the JavaConfig object, but not too thrilled about it - it seems a little "hacky" to me:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    // other @Bean definitions

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`MethodInvokingBean` will be the de facto choice for add `BouncyCastleProvider` to `java.security.Security` since you won't need any exposure to your application context.